# Offline Authentication in Android app using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, mobile

i'm kind of new to android dev and am working on an app that requires login. I've seen how to make authentication using firebase, but my issue is I need this app to be completely offline as i'm making it for the games room that I run at my county college, and the internet is absolutely awful.

The only way i've been able to figure out in my own head was to just reference a file saved on the tablet and check the logins there. While this would work, it's not the most secure. I was wondering if there was a better way of going about offline authentication that's a little bit more secure.

Not sure if it matters but i'll also have different account types, such as admin and employee. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want ho protect by such an authentication?

Answer (score 0):

**Offline Authentication does not have any feature of Admin panel**

Normally Authentication is done for which are the user are logged in or logged out from remote service such as firebase,google cloud etc,..  Without these offline auth is simply waste don't inculde any control over for our app